# Breaking Conservation of energy with fluids?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

“Suppose that the build-up of fatty tissue on the wall of an artery decreased the radius by 10%. By how much would the pressure provided by the heart have to be increased to maintain a constant blood flow”?

The relevant math: (v = velocity) 
A1*V1 = A2*V2 
(pi * (1^2)) V1 = (pi* (0.9^2)) V2 
Ratio of the velocities = 100/81

Is this a possible scenario? If the problem abides by conservation of energy and a constant flow rate, then an increase in the velocity due to the reduced radius should mean that there is a lower pressure compared to the original rather than an increase in pressure. Given this, how could the pressure increase and the velocity increase as well?

Comment: Constriction increases resistance to the flow. That's why you need higher pressure difference to achieve the same blood flow rate.

Comment: To expand on what Deep said, the Bernoulli equation assumes that mechanical energy is conserved, and is not dissipated (say to increasing the temperature slightly).  But, in flow of fluids through pipes and tubes, there is typically viscous dissipation of mechanical energy, and associated flow resistance.